# AR Application using Unity (Motion Tracking and Real Time Positioning)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, game-engine, unreal-engine4

I want to create an AR Application, this AR Application should be able to do these things,

1. track position in real time depending on a local coordination system used in unity.
2. move the character/object each time i move in real life
3. AR should be able to recognize the objects from the model in real life depending on the coordination system, so if the coordinates of the wall are 0,0,0 and in real life am standing in 0,0,1 then if i move my mobile camera onto position 0,0,0 i should be able to recognize the object.

what are your ideas of how to get started on something like this, what are the names of the topics i should search for, and how hard is it to actually create this?

i've got nowhere til now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depend on what device you'll use to do AR. Is it an headset like a quest 3 or a Hololens, is it a smartphone with a camera ?

- For Quest 3, check the meta XR package on Unity, they explain a lot
  about AR : [doc](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/unity-passthrough/)
- For Hololens, check the [MRTK3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk3-overview/) and some tuto on the microsoft
- For a smartphone, check for [Vuforia](https://developer.vuforia.com/library/) of ARCore for unity : [demo](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/arcore-unity-ar-foundation#0)